# batch file to delete folder in subdirectory kepping leatest one

Tags: batch-file

i want to delete previous days backup folder, folder must have some files.
(i have directory stucture like : d:/backup/pc-1/day1 d:/backup/pc-1/day2 d:/backup/pc-2/day1 d:/backup/pc-2/day2 after delete it will be ... d:/backup/pc-1/day2 d:/backup/pc-2/day2)

please help me on following issue...

---

i have directory stucture like :

```
d:/backup/pc-1/day1
d:/backup/pc-1/day2
d:/backup/pc-2/day1
d:/backup/pc-2/day2
```

---

after delete it will be ...

```
d:/backup/pc-1/day2
d:/backup/pc-2/day2
```

---

thanks

Comment: What have you tried already. What worked? What didn't work? Usually, people don't just write code for you. It might help if you paid them, though. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### alphabetical sort, `day2` > `day1`:

```
for /d %%d in (d:\backup\*) do for /f "skip=1delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /o-n "%%~d\*" 2^>nul') do echo rd /s /q "%%~d\%%~a"
```

Remove `echo` to make it working.

Comment: getting %%d was unexpected at this time.

Comment: the code is batch script code, not cmd line. To use it on the cmd prompt you need only one percent sign: `%a` and `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cd "c:\some_dir"
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%f in  ('dir /b /ad /o-d /tc ') do (
  rd /s /q "%%~dpfnsf"
)
```

? (the skip parameter controls how many dirs will be spared for the deletion) (`dir /b /ad /o-d /tc` sorts the directories by creation date in reverse order)